# Dependency Injection with package service provider not being detected

Tags: laravel

I am trying to utilize a service provider from a custom package:

```
class ReferralsServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
    {
        public const PACKAGE_NAME = 'referrals';
    
        /**
         * Perform post-registration booting of services.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function boot()
        {
            ...
        }
    
        /**
         * Register the application services.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function register()
        {
            $this->app->bind(PreReferralsRepositoryInterface::class, WorkflowPreReferrals::class);
        }
```

The service provider is registered in the packages composer.json file so it's auto-registered in the utilizing application.

```
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
      "providers": [
        "Propel\\Referrals\\ReferralsServiceProvider"
      ]
    }
  }
```

However in one of the controllers we have in main application:

```
class ReferalValidationController extends Controller
{
    protected $referrals;

    public function __construct(PreReferralsRepositoryInterface $referrals)
    {
        ...
    }
```

I get the error:

```
Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\ReferalValidationController::__construct() must be an instance of Propel\Referrals\Repositories\PreReferralsRepositoryInterface, instance of Propel\Referrals\Repositories\WorkflowPreReferrals given
```

I know for a fact the service provider is registered as I can change the second parameter of the binding to another class and it will then reflect in the error. Have I missed out something critical in the binding? Its almost as if the controller is unaware of the service provider.

Comment: Check if WorkflowPreReferrals is implementing PreReferralsRepositoryInterface.

Comment: Spot on, completely missed this , always something silly ahah.